# WebMethod in .aspx page to connect to database

Tags: asp.net, sql, webmethod

I put the WebMethod script below in my .aspx page to connect to my database. However, it seems that I need to put "using System.Data" and "using System.SqlClient" somewhere to use ADO.NET. Can I use WebMethod in .aspx page (not.aspx.cs page) to connect to the database, and if so how should I use it?

```
<script runat="server">

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void send()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Hello;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Why the requirement to put in the .aspx page and not the aspx.cs page?

Comment: I did this to use WebMethod. Can I use WebMethod in the pages other than .asmx page or .aspx page?

Comment: You can put it in the page.aspx.cs (code-behind). You will need to add  "using System.Data;" and "using System.Data.SqlClient;" at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try

```
<script runat="server">
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void send()
{
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Hello;Integrated Security=True");
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, con);
using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}

</script>
```